# Using Run PsScriptanalyzer in azure devops CI pipeline

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-extensions

When I am trying to run a simple `.ps1` file in `Run PsScriptanalyzer` plugin in Azure DevOps CI pipeline. The `Run PsScriptanalyzer` task status is continuously running and it isn't getting Completed nor Failed.

The output is:

```
##[warning]Task 'RunPsScriptAnalyzer' (1.0.2443) is using deprecated task execution handler. The task should use the supported task-lib: https://aka.ms/tasklib


Starting: Run PsScriptAnalyzer 
==============================================================================
Task         : Run PsScriptAnalyzer
Description  : Tests if PsScriptAnalyzer is installed, and if not will install the module and run it against folder path.
Version      : 1.0.2443
Author       : Richie Lee
Help         : [More Information](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer)
==============================================================================
##[warning]Task 'RunPsScriptAnalyzer' (1.0.2443) is using deprecated task execution handler. The task should use the supported task-lib: https://aka.ms/tasklib
Preparing task execution handler.
Executing the powershell script: D:\a\_tasks\RunPsScriptAnalyzer_1bf78f8b-8e90-4715-abf4-daf7060d7a1e\1.0.2443\RunPsScriptAnalyzer.ps1

 PsScriptAnalyzer Imported


File 'test.ps1' uses Write-Host. Avoid using Write-Host because it might not work in all hosts, does not work when there is no host, and (prior to PS 5.0) cannot be suppressed, captured, or redirected. Instead, use Write-Output, Write-Verbose, or Write-Information.


Write-Host "Hello, World!"


PSAvoidUsingWriteHost
```

Answer (score 1):

The task PsScriptanalyzer from extension: [PowerShell ScriptAnalyzer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ToreGroneng.ToreGroneng-PSScriptAnalyzer-Task) extension is a deprecated task.

I can reproduce the same issue. And many other users have the same issue.

You can refer to [this Extension QA](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ToreGroneng.ToreGroneng-PSScriptAnalyzer-Task&ssr=false#qna). Since this extension has been deprecated, it has not been maintained for a long time.

I suggest that you can use another extension([Powershell Syntax Validation](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BlackMarble.PowershellSyntaxValidation-Public&ssr=false#overview)) to replace the PowerShell ScriptAnalyzer.

This extension has the similar feature and it can work as expected.